# Assembler errors

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I am a begginer with asm, and do not understand why (using TASM) it thows me errors. The code is:

```
.MODEL LARGE
.386
.STACK 200h
.DATA
    main_pi dd ?
    _1c dd 1.0 
.CODE
    MOV ax, @DATA
    MOV ds, ax
    JMP salto0
salto0:
    MOV main_pi, _1c
    MOV ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
END
```

The errors are:

> *Warning* final.asm(3) Assuming segment is 32-bit
>   **Error** final.asm(13) Illegal memory reference

Any help? Thanks !!

Comment: `MOV` doesn't take 2 memory operands. You have to go through a register.

Comment: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

Thanks !!!